# Which database should be chosen in Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, heroku

I want to migrate a database to [Heroku](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heroku). The old database is exported to some [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) files, but now I don't know how to select the database in Heroku.

My issue is:

- The data is always increasing, so in the future, there will be a lot of data. Which database is available for this?
- I can only get JSON files from my old database. Can it be imported into the Heroku database?
- My users are mostly in America. The database in Heroku whether lead the user's access speed slowly or not?
- My project is using [Ruby on Rails](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruby_on_Rails).

What should I do?

Answer (score 2):

It's better that you specify the database you currently use for your application. If you give more information, I will update my answer.

But firstly, reading the article *[Moving a Rails App to Heroku](http://webandy.com/articles/26-moving-a-rails-app-to-heroku)* will help you a lot with moving the application to Heroku.

1. Heroku has addons from another provider. The only database they provide is [PostgreSQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostgreSQL) which is very nice and suitable for many kind of applications. It's just brilliant.
2. Read the mentioned article above.
3. If you create your application in Heroku, it will be located in the USA by default. I don't know if Heroku optimizes to the location of your application and addons or not, but normally if you have something slow in your application, it's your fault, not Heroku's.
4. Yes! Heroku loves Ruby on Rails

Comment: Thanks for your reply!My project used the service of Parse,the address is parse.com,the service is that I can store my data in it like storing in a database,but its sdk has some issues when I query the data from 'database',so I want to migrate it to heroku.Now I can export the data from it,and the data are .json files,so do my issues have any ways to fixed?    Thanks again,guy~

Comment: Now it's more clear that you use the API service from Parse. Firstly, you need to update your question and then I will update my answer. It's better that way so the others can follow what we are trying to solve :)

Comment: yea,okay,let me describe again.the parse's database has a issue that I can only get 1000 rows data for once query,but I hope I can get more,and its sdk don't permit,I don't know whether the heroku has this same issue or not.And I also want to write REST APIs for heroku's database by myself,not to use that of heroku if heroku has provide it,for example,if I use postgresql,those are permitted?

Comment: Also I have got the information that the PostgreSQL's "Connection Limit" is 500 at most,I want to know what the means of the parameter "Connection Limit"，Thanks

Comment: The connection limit term describes how many connection it can serve concurrently.
If your application is more about live updating and real time application, you better choose something like mongodb. But it's better you should separate this to another question ( And remember to search before posting :) )

Answer (score 2):

First of all, Heroku provides [PostgreSQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostgreSQL) as the default database. It might be the following reasons for use it.

1. PostgreSQL is a powerful, open source object-relational database system.
2. Heroku Postgres is the SQL database service run by Heroku that is provisioned and managed as an `add-on`.
3. Heroku Postgres is accessible from any language with a PostgreSQL driver including all languages and frameworks supported by Heroku: Java, Ruby, Python, [Scala](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scala_%28programming_language%29), Play, [Node.js](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node.js) and [Clojure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clojure).

For more you can refer this http://www.postgresql.org/about/advantages/.